# Do you have good book tiltles to give me about video game programming?

Tags: c++, opengl, directx, shader

I already program in C#, Java and C++ and would like to know if you know good books (wether about OpenGL or DirectX and with any of these languages) that cover video game development and that include a discussion about shaders, special effects, sound and collision detection.  I know this may seem a lot, but I searched on Amazon and O'Reilly and didn't find a book that covers all these subjects.  I don't know if you have seen a book like this.

Comment: This would be a good question to ask on the game developers version of stack overflow: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You're going to want lots of different books ultimately. Shaders, special effects, sound and collision all have books devoted to them. Not sure what to tell you about an "overview".

Comment: Check these questions to get you started: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=books

Answer (score 1):

Jay Baxter of Blizzard Entertainment has posted a list of books that are recommended reading for aspiring programmers at his company.  You can view his lists of recommended game programming books [here](http://www.amazon.com/gp/richpub/listmania/byauthor/A3VCLPFBQG9OUU/ref=cm_pdp_lm_all).

Answer (score 0):

A broad (not in depth) book that touches those topics among many others is [Core Techniques and Algorithms in Game Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131020099). I highly recommend it.

> [...] this book is exactly what I was
>   looking for. After reading it (and
>   re-reading some passages) the
>   difference with other books on games
>   is appalling: this is a course on
>   games programming, a tool for those
>   who want a formal, well laid-out
>   introduction, that covers all the main
>   topics and leaves few questions
>   unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a MASSIVE amount of information and if there ARE any books out there that cover all of these, I'm fairly sure that they wouldn't really go into any amount of depth on each.

Both the [DirectX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/directx/bb896684) and [OpenGL](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/) websites have pretty much all information that you'll need for either graphics API. If you're not so interested in the actual plumbing work, then I'd suggest maybe taking a look at [Ogre](http://www.ogre3d.org/) (which I believe also has a [C# port](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/OgreDotNet)).

Shader documentation: [DirectX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb509635%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [OpenGL](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/glsl/)

Audio all depends on the the API that you end up going with: [DirectX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee416799%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), or you can choose from many OS audio libraries out there (i.e. [OpenAL](http://connect.creativelabs.com/openal/default.aspx)).

For special effects, I'd recommend the [Graphics Gems](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=graphics+gems&x=0&y=0) series, as well as [GPU Gems](http://developer.nvidia.com/object/gpu_gems_home.html).

I'm not too sure about specific collision detection references, as I usually just end up google'ing for algorithms on demand.

The [Game Programming Gems](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=game+programming+gems&x=0&y=0) series is a great source for information, but it's more tips 'n tricks and not a thorough explanation of each topic.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard from others that ["Essential Mathematics for Games and Interactive Applications"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123742978) is a good start to building your foundation and (re)familiarizing yourself with the math aspects.